# Programming in UNIX - Semaphores,shared memory in C

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory, semaphore

I started a week ago understanding and working with semaphores and shared memory, and actually created this program, the problem is i cant find anything wrong with it i been looking at it for hours and everything seems correct.. The code compiles and i can create the build but when i execute it nothing happens ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define MAXCHILDS 4
#define MAX_SIZE 10
#define MAX_WRITES 4

typedef struct{
    int m[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
} matrix;

/*fork variables*/
pid_t child[MAXCHILDS];
/*semphores variables */
sem_t *empty, *full, * mutex;
/*share memory id*/
int shmid;
/*shared memory array pointer */
matrix * sh_mem;
/*pointer to matrix*/
int **p;


void init(){
      /*create pointer to matrix*/
      p = &sh_mem->m;
     /*semaphores unlink and creation */    
     sem_unlink("EMPTY");
     empty=sem_open("EMPTY",O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0700,MAX_WRITES);
     sem_unlink("FULL");
     full=sem_open("FULL",O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0700,0);
     sem_unlink("MUTEX");
     mutex=sem_open("MUTEX",O_CREAT|O_EXCL,0700,1);
    /*initialize shared memory */
    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(matrix),IPC_CREAT|0777);
    /*map shared memory*/
    sh_mem = (matrix*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
    if(sh_mem== (matrix*)(-1)){
        perror("shmat");
    }
}
void writer(int ** m){
    int i,k;
    for(i = 0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
        for(k= 0;k<MAX_SIZE;k++){
            m[i][k] = 0;
        }
    }

}
void reader(int **m){
    int i = 0;
    int k = 0;
    for(i = 0;i<MAX_SIZE;i++){
        for(k= 0;k<MAX_SIZE;k++){
            printf(m[i][k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}

void terminate() {
  sem_close(empty);
  sem_close(full);
  sem_close(mutex);
  sem_unlink("EMPTY");
  sem_unlink("FULL");
  sem_unlink("MUTEX");
  shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    init();

    for(i = 0;i<MAXCHILDS;i++){
        if((child[i]= fork()) < 0) // error occured
        {
            perror("Fork Failed");
            exit(1);
        }
        if((child[i] =fork())==0){
            writer(p);
            exit(0);
        }
    }
    /*father*/  
    reader(p);
    wait(NULL);

    terminate();


    return 0;
}
```

The childs are supposed to write the the matrix in shared memory, and the father is supposed to read the shared memory array and the print the matrix.
Can you help me with this? Thanks for the help ...

Comment: The first strange thing is that you call `fork` twice in the loop and assign the result to one variable. I'm quite sure you want to call it only once and save the result in a variable and use _that_ twice .

Comment: Offhand, I can see that your `main()` function looks like a bit of a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb) since the process forks and both parent and child go through for loop again. Other that that, I think it might be helpful if you said what the program was SUPPOSED to do instead of just saying it does nothing.

Comment: @Celada: Na, I guess only 3 * `MAXCHILDS` are created. This is not a real fork bomb ;-)

Comment: Thanks for answering this fast, the childs are supposed to write to the matrix in shared memory and the father is supposed to read from it.

Comment: Yea for now i only need one child but after i resolve this issue i want to divide the matrix for the childs ...if you can help me to find why this doesnt work ... its supposed to print the matrix that is read by the father from the shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

- You declare your `p` variable as follows:

  ```
  int **p;
  ```

  But the actual type of your array is `int[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE]`. Although those can both be considered 2-dimensional arrays, they are not at all the same type and do not share the same structure in memory:

  - `int **` is a pointer to a pointer to an integer. When used as a 2-dimensional array, it describes a 2-level array. The first level (dereferencing the pointer once) contains an array of `int *` pointers that each point to 1-dimensional arrays of integers.
  - `int[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE]` is a flat 2-dimentional array. It is a single pointer to an array of `MAXSIZE*MAXSIZE` integers. It has the same memory structure as the 1-dimensional array `int[MAXSIZE*MAXSIZE]` even though it offers the convenience of using 2 levels of subscripts.

  Passing around pointers to `type[][]`-style arrays in C is non-intuitive and very difficult to get right. I don't advise doing it. You might consider passing pointers to your `matrix` type instead. Still, it is possible to get it to work with this declaration:

  ```
  typedef int array2d[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
  array2d *p;
  ```

  then you have to change the `m` parameter in `reader` and `writer` to `array2d *m` instead or `int **m` and use it as `*m` instead of just `m`. This gets ugly. Like I said, consider using your `matrix` type instead.

  This problem should have been caught by the compiler. It should have been giving you lots of type mismatch warnings. Make sure you always compile with `gcc -Wall` and aim to have your program compile with no errors and no warnings.
- In `init()`, you set `p` too early. You should set it at the end of the function after `sh_mem` has been assigned, not at the start of the function.
- You are `fork()`ing too many processes in your `main()` function, as discussed in comments above. You probably meant to call `fork()` only once each time through the `for` loop, not twice.
- You don't wait until the writers have finished filling out the shared memory structure before you go ahead and read its contents.

  Note that even if you move your `wait(NULL)` before the call to `reader()`, that's not enough, since `wait(NULL)` will only wait for one child process to complete, not all of them.

In general, you should compile your program with warnings enabled, pay attention to the warnings, and fix them before wondering what might be wrong with your program. If it still does something unexpected, you should run it under a debugger, use breakpoints, inspect variables, and try to take a look at what's happening. Using these two techniques, you probably would have solved your problem without needing to post here.