# UNIX Shared Memory

Tags: c, unix, shared-memory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unix Programming Shared Memory strange results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234990/unix-programming-shared-memory-strange-results)

I have been doing and learning how to use shared memory for two weeks now, and in a smaller exercice i could make it work but now im having problems in the following code in relation to other sequencial code that i made ... the output just is the same and doesnt get to calculation like the sequencial version ... and the code is the same ...

This is the shared memory code:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 20

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h> 
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAXCHILDS 2
#define MAX_SIZE 20
#define MAX_WRITES 100
#define ALIVE 1
#define DEAD 0


typedef struct{
    int m[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
    int h[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
}matrix;

pid_t child[MAXCHILDS];
matrix*sh_mem;
int shmid;
int gen = 5; 


void calculate() { // filhos checks if the cells around obey these rules are changed to 1 or 0 
        int tableB[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE];
        int neighbor, height, width;


        for (height = 0; height < MAX_SIZE; height++) {
                for (width = 0; width < MAX_SIZE; width++) {
                        neighbor = getNeighborCount(sh_mem->m, height, width);
                        if (neighbor==3) {
                                tableB[height][width] = ALIVE;
                        } else if (neighbor == 2 && sh_mem->m[height][width] == ALIVE) {
                                tableB[height][width] = ALIVE;
                        } else {
                                tableB[height][width] = DEAD;
                        }
                }
        }

        for (height = MAX_SIZE; height < MAX_SIZE; height++) {
                for (width = MAX_SIZE; width < MAX_SIZE; width++) {
                        sh_mem->m[height][width] = tableB[height][width];
                }
        }
}
int getNeighborValue(int table[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int row, int col) { // gets the neighborvalue
        if (table[row][col] == ALIVE) 
        { 
                return 1;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}
int getNeighborCount(int table[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE], int row, int col) { // gets the cells around 
        int neighbor = 0;

        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col - 1);  //top left
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col);  //top
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col + 1);  //top right
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col - 1);  //left
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col + 1);  //right
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col - 1);  //below left
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col);   // below
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col + 1);  //below right

        return neighbor;
}
void printTable(int table[MAX_SIZE][MAX_SIZE]) {
        int height, width;

        for (height = 0; height < MAX_SIZE-1; height++) {
                for (width = 0; width < MAX_SIZE-1; width++) {
                        if (table[height][width] == 1) {
                                printf(" X ");
                        } else {
                                printf(" . ");
                        }
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}
void init(){

    /*initialize shared memory */
    shmid = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE,sizeof(matrix),IPC_CREAT|0777);
    /*map shared memory*/
    sh_mem = (matrix*)shmat(shmid,NULL,0);
    if(sh_mem == (matrix*)(-1)){
        perror("shmat");
    }
}
void terminate() {
  shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
}

void initarray() {
  int i,j; 
  for (i=0; i<MAX_SIZE-1; i++){
    for (j=0; j<MAX_SIZE-1; j++){
        if(drand48()>0.5){
            sh_mem->m[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else{
            sh_mem->m[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
} 


int matchArray(){ // funcao para o parent // checks the matrix for differences with previous matrix
        int count = 0;
        int height,width,flag=0;
        for(height = 0; height<MAX_SIZE; height++){
                for(width = 0; width<MAX_SIZE; width++){
                        if(sh_mem->m[height][width] != sh_mem->h[height][width]){
                                count++;
                        }
                }
        }
        if(count>0){
                flag = 1;
        }
        return flag;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
    int i,k;
    int generation = 0;
    int height,width;
    int flag = 0;
    init();
    initarray(sh_mem->m);
    printTable(sh_mem->m);
    printf("Test data as Generation 0\n");
    printf("-----------\n");


      for(i=0; i<gen; i++)
    {
                for (height = 0; height < MAX_SIZE; height++) {
                    for (width = 0; width < MAX_SIZE; width++) {
                            sh_mem->h[height][width] = sh_mem->m[height][width];
                    }
                }
                calculate();
                flag = matchArray();
                printf("The flag value is:%d\n",flag);
                if(flag == 0){
                    break;
                }
                        printTable(sh_mem->m);
                printf("\n======================================\n");
                printTable(sh_mem->h);
                        printf("Generation %d\n", ++generation);
        }

    return 0;
}
```

The sequentional version is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

#define ALIVE 1
#define DEAD 0

int **array = NULL;
int **history = NULL;
int HEIGHT;
int WIDTH;

double gettime(void) {
  struct timeval tval;

  gettimeofday(&tval, NULL);

  return( (double)tval.tv_sec + (double)tval.tv_usec/1000000.0 );
}

//Its showing answer with small size matrices, but not with bigger ones

int **allocarray(int P, int Q) {
  int i;
  int *p, **a;
  p = (int *)malloc(P*Q*sizeof(int));
  a = (int **)malloc(P*sizeof(int*));
  if (p == NULL || a == NULL) 
    printf("Error allocating memory\n");
  /* for row major storage */
  for (i = 0; i < P; i++)
    a[i] = &p[i*Q];
  return a;
}
void initarray() {
  int i,j; 
  for (i=1; i<HEIGHT-1; i++){
    for (j=1; j<WIDTH-1; j++){
        if(drand48()>0.5){
            array[i][j] = 1;
        }
        else{
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
  }
} 
void printTable(int **table) {
        int height, width;

        for (height = 1; height < HEIGHT-1; height++) {
                for (width = 1; width < WIDTH-1; width++) {
                        if (table[height][width] == ALIVE) {
                                printf(" X ");
                        } else {
                                printf(" 0 ");
                        }
                }
                printf("\n");
        }
        printf("\n");
}

//to clear up everything

void clearTable() {
        int height, width;
        for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
                for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                        array[height][width] = DEAD;
                }
        }
}

int getNeighborValue(int **table, int row, int col) {
        if (table[row][col] == ALIVE) 
        { 
                return 1;
        } else {
                return 0;
        }
}


int getNeighborCount(int **table, int row, int col) {
        int neighbor = 0;

        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col - 1);  //top left
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col);  //top
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row - 1, col + 1);  //top right
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col - 1);  //left
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row, col + 1);  //right
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col - 1);  //below left
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col);   // below
        neighbor += getNeighborValue(table, row + 1, col + 1);  //below right

        return neighbor;
}

void calculate() {
        int **tableB = NULL;
        int neighbor, height, width;
        tableB = allocarray(HEIGHT, WIDTH);

        for (height = 1; height < (HEIGHT-1); height++) {
                for (width = 1; width < (WIDTH-1); width++) {
                        neighbor = getNeighborCount(array, height, width);
                        if (neighbor==3) {
                                tableB[height][width] = ALIVE;
                        } else if (neighbor == 2 && array[height][width] == ALIVE) {
                                tableB[height][width] = ALIVE;
                        } else {
                                tableB[height][width] = DEAD;
                        }
                }
        }

        for (height = 1; height < (HEIGHT-1); height++) {
                for (width = 1; width < (WIDTH-1); width++) {
                        array[height][width] = tableB[height][width];
                }
        }
}

int matchArray(){
        int count = 0;
        int height,width,flag=0;
        for(height = 0; height<HEIGHT; height++){
                for(width = 0; width<WIDTH; width++){
                        if(array[height][width] != history[height][width]){
                                count++;
                        }
                }
        }
        if(count>0){
                flag = 1;
        }
        return flag;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        int generation = 0;
        int i;
        double starttime, endtime, time;
        int height,width;
        int flag = 0;
    if (argc!=3)
        printf("You need to enter the size of the matrix and the number of generations in the comment line arguement\n");
    else
    {
        printf("The matrix size given is:%s\n",argv[1]);
        HEIGHT = atoi(argv[1])+2;
        WIDTH = HEIGHT;
        array = allocarray(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        history = allocarray(HEIGHT, WIDTH);
        clearTable();
        // askUser(table);
        //loadTestData(array);
        initarray();
        printTable(array);
        printf("Test data as Generation 0\n");
        printf("-----------\n");
        starttime= gettime();
        printf("Starttime= %f", starttime);
        for(i=0; i<(atoi(argv[2])); i++)
    {
                for (height = 0; height < HEIGHT; height++) {
                    for (width = 0; width < WIDTH; width++) {
                            history[height][width] = array[height][width];
                    }
                }
                calculate();
                flag = matchArray();
                printf("The flag value is:%d\n",flag);
                if(flag == 0){
                    break;
                }
                        printTable(array);
                printf("\n======================================\n");
                printTable(history);
                        printf("Generation %d\n", ++generation);
        }
    endtime= gettime();
    printf("Endtime= %f", endtime);

    time= (endtime-starttime);
    printf("Time taken= %1f\n", time); 
    } 
        return 0;
}
```

Now the problem is the second version runs well and the matrix evolves through the rules i defined in calculate function, but the in the first code its always the same ... and doesnt even envolve at all ...the two versions are working and ready to compile ...
If you can help me fix this i would be very appreciated.

Comment: its not even a duplicate i dont even use the same functions, the code is distinctly different than that code ...if you dont want to help why bother?

Comment: This comment was not meant to be an answer. Also I tried to indicate this using the acronym OT for "Off Topic". The relation to your code is, that I stumbled over this misspelling while reading the code.

Comment: Could you elaborate? The programs are not identical, one takes arguments, one does not; they have different output. What should be the correct result?

Comment: that is not constructive ... i know that children is plural but that isnt even relevant for the coding porposes ...

Comment: You seem to have posted 4 almost identical questions on this same subject now - maybe you need to break the problem down into more manageable chunks ?

Comment: xavier the correct result should be something like the second code...

Comment: the program evolves for the time the output is something like this: 10000000,1100000 but in larger array and through generations it evolves to a more bigger form

Comment: The code differs. For example, in the second one you iterate to `HEIGHT` and `WIDTH` in `main` and to `HEIGHT-1` in calculate - which is different from the first one. It's really hard to debug, when they DO differ. Make it the same, then we can debug.

Comment: @DestPT It's been my experience that when other users post comments, even ones that may suggest corrections, possible duplicate questions, or asking for further information, they're not attempting to be snarky or judgmental... they genuinely want to make SO a better place (read: help out all users, even future ones googling for this question). Now... It's up to you, but if a user suggests fixing a typo or checking another question, you may want to cut them some slack.. after all, they took time out of their day to read your question...

Comment: @DestPT All of that being said, I'm still going to +1 your question, because I believe you took the time to describe your issue, and presented all of the existing code ahead of time.

Comment: Thanks for your opinion, you understood me very well ... i want to make SO a better place too...It wasnt my porpuse to be this aggressive, im just having a hard time and i thought i did expose my problem well ... but i will take it into consideration and make it better for people to understand me ...

Comment: @DestPT will you modify the sources to be identical wherever possible? Then I could try to help.

Comment: How many arguments does `initarray` take?

Comment: initarray fills up the memory shared multidimensional array m that is defined in a global variable of struct type...so it doesnt take any variable ...

Comment: xavier i will try to make it identical ... Thanks for your time

Comment: In the shared version: `initarray(sh_mem->m);`.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that error it doesnt take any argument but i pass that one by mistake- the function is `void initarray()`